# If Chern classes are only defined for vector bundles, why can a $U(1)$ principal bundle have associated Chern classes?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

When people talk about Chern classes of $U(1)$ principal bundles, do they really mean the Chern class of the associated vector bundle? As far as I can understand, Chern classes exist only for complex vector bundles, which $U(1)$ is not, so I don't understand why it makes sense to talk about Chern classes/numbers for a $U(1)$ bundle.

Comment: They mean the associated vector bundle. People tend to freely interchange principal bundles with their associated vector bundle.